# quasi-affine varieties: why is $Z(I(Y))=\overline{Y}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y\subset\mathbb{A}^n$ be a quasi-affine variety, and assume $Y$ to be an open set in $\mathbb{A}^n$. Also let $A$ be the polnomial ring in $n$ indeterminates over an algebraically closed field. The statement $Z(I(Y))=\overline{Y}$, the closure of $Y$ is given. I know that the open sets are dense in $\mathbb{A}^n$, so the closure $\overline{Y}$ is $\mathbb{A}^n$. Let me assume that the closed complement of $Y$ is $Y^c$, which contains a point $P$. In my opinion, $I(Y)$ does not contain the irreducible linear polynomials $f$ with $f(P)=0$ and $P\in Y^c$. Nevertheless, why is $P\in Z(I(Y))=\mathbb{A}^n$?

Comment: I think you should read the definition of quasi-affine variety one more time.

Comment: So, a set can be an open subset of an affine variety, but in turn is not an open subset in $\mathbb{A}^n$? Of course, if it is an open subset of an affine variety $X\subsetneq\mathbb{A}^n$, then it is not dense in $\mathbb{A}^n$. Secondly, if I assume that $Y$ is an open subset in the affine variety $\mathbb{A}^n$, how would you answer my question? I will adapt my question slightly.

Comment: @user823 $[0,1)$ is open set in $[0,1]$, but not open in $\mathbb R$ in the usual topology.

Comment: @Ennar I think that an argument akin to the argument that would be used for your example holds in $\mathbb{A}^n$ as well. I believe that $\mathbb{A}^n$ is an affine variety, because of irreducibility due to $I(\mathbb{A}^n)=(0)$, the zero ideal of $A$ which is a prime ideal.

Comment: @user823 my example is to show how relative topology works in general. If $A$ is open in $B$, it doesn't have to be open in $C$ unless $B$ is open in $C$, for $A\subseteq B \subseteq C$ and relative topology on $B$ coming from $C$. $\mathbb{A}^n$ is an affine variety, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I answer my question for the general case where the quasi-affine variety $Y$ is not dense in $\mathbb{A}^n$, so let $Y$ be an open subset of a proper closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$, which was an aspect that was correctly pointed out to be missing in my question. The case where $Y$ is dense in $\mathbb{A}^n$ can then be easily seen from this more general case.

It is known that $I$ and its inverse $Z$ describe a bijective correspondence between closed sets in $\mathbb{A}^n$ and radical ideals of $A$.

Let $X$ be a variety in $\mathbb{A}^n$. Consider the definition of the map $I:\mathbb{A}^n\rightarrow A$ by

$$Y\subset \mathbb{A}^n\mapsto \{f\in A|f(P)=0,\forall P\in Y\},$$

where $Y\subset X$ is a quasi-affine variety in $\mathbb{A}^n$ and $A$ the polynomial ring over $k$ in $n$ indeterminates. Then I reminded myself that $f$ can also be seen as a continuous map from $\mathbb{A}^n$ to $\mathbb{A}^1$. Now, clearly $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^1$, so the preimage of $\{0\}$ under $f$ is a closed set as well, by continuity.

Since for any element $f\in A$ we have $$f^{-1}(\{0\})\subset\mathbb{A}^n$$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$ and the set

$$Z(I(Y))=\{f^{-1}(\{0\})\subset\mathbb{A}^n|f\in I(Y)\}$$

certainly covers $Y$. On the other hand, we have $$Z(I(Y))\subseteq X,$$

since $I(Y)\supseteq I(X)$ because $I(...)$ is known to be inclusion-reversing and by basic arguments $Z(I(X))=X$.

Furthermore, the smallest closed subset containing $Y$ is $X$, by the assumption of density of $Y$ in $X$, therefore

$$Z(I(Y))=\overline{Y}=X.$$

To describe a geometric picture, for the points $X\setminus{Y
}$ we have $f(X\setminus{Y})=0$ for all $f\in I(Y)$, which is the main point of the argument.